# Максимальный обьем кучи С++

Tags: c++, память

Какой максимальный обьем кучи? 
Если у стека приблизительно: 4 MB?

Comment: Сколько даст железо и ОС.

Comment: В линуксе стек тоже не ограничен при соответствующей настройке

Comment: Какая у вас ОС? Windows? Linux? Какая разрядность? 32 бита? 64?

Answer (score 1):

В случае Windows максимальный объём доступной кучи задаётся в параметрах исполняемого EXE-файла.

Причём помимо максимального (зарезервированного) объёма указывается ещё и начальный, выделяемый сразу же при загрузке программы и увеличиваемый впоследствии.

Соответственно, вы можете настраивать эти размеры через свойства проекта в категории Linker → System. Это "Heap Reserve Size"  и "Heap Commit Size" соответственно.

Comment: Это неверный ответ. Оба параметра регулируют начальный размер кучи. А реальное ограничение регулируется квотой на процесс (которую можно изменять при наличии соответствующей привилегии).

Answer (score 0):

Максимальный объем кучи жестко ограничен размером адресного пространства процесса на вашей платформе. Понятно, что в приложении с 32-битным адресным пространством объем кучи не может превышать 4GB.

Если же размер адресного пространства не является насущным ограничивающим фактором, то на первый план выходят текущие настройки ОС и вашего процесса. От этом уже у вас надо спрашивать.

P.S. Что вы хотели сказать вашим "Если у стека приблизительно: 4 MB" - не совсем понятно.

Comment: Почему ограничен адресным пространством? Есть ли такое в стандарте?

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalyan: Каким образом вы собираетесь представлять указатели, "не помещающиеся" в адресное пространство?

Comment: Подходящим кол-вом байтов, например 5 байтов, если хотим больше 4гиг адресовать.

Comment: Ну под "адресным пространством" я имею в виду модель памяти процесса в рамках С++ платформы. Если у вас в С++ платформе реализованы 5-байтовые указатели при 4-байтовом адресном пространстве ОС-процесса - то да, можно и больше.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, 32-разрядный процессор не поймёт вашего пятибайтового указателя.

Comment: @Arhad Почему не поймет, он же умеет с uin64_t (за несколько операций) работать например.

Comment: `объем кучи не может превышать 4GB` — из-за разделяемой памяти ядра — двух (иногда трёх). Плюс не стоит забывать про стеки потоков и образы библиотек, которые тоже занимают часть адресного пространства.

Comment: @Arhad [вот](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZX_Spectrum#ZX_Spectrum_128) пример, когда процессор с 64-к адресным пространством работает с 128 кб (страничная организация) памяти. А менеджер памяти обеспечивает прозрачное использование страниц для указателей.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, счётчик команд (`eip`) 32-разрядный. Как вы туда 64 бита поместите?

Comment: @Arhad а туда и не нужно его помещать, это же только деталь реализации

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, на IBM PC-архитектуре тоже есть подобная технология, PAE называется. Вот только работать с ней можно исключительно из привелегированного режима.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71653/discussion-between-vladimir-gamalyan-and-arhad).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan: Это замечательно, но это не имеет прямого отношения к С++ куче, каковая является темой данного вопроса.

Comment: @AnT не понял, что "это" ?